# Cash register outputs string of denominations in which to give change. Input is purchase price and cash given

Tags: java, linkedhashmap

I don't know why when iterating through my linkedhashmap to find the smallest possible combination of denominations to give as change in this piece of code, when iterating through "Five pence", the program fails and gives an erroneous final output.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;


public class Main {
    /**
     * Iterate through each line of input.
     */

    public static LinkedHashMap<Integer, String> cashMap = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, String>(){{
        put(5000,"Fifty Pounds");
        put(2000, "Twenty Pounds");
        put(1000, "Ten Pounds");
        put(500, "Five Pounds");
        put(200, "Two Pounds");
        put(100, "One Pound");
        put(50, "Fifty Pence");
        put(20, "Twenty Pence");
        put(10, "Ten Pence");
        put(5, "Five Pence");
        put(2, "Two Pence");
        put(1, "One Pence");
    }};

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(reader);

        try {
            double purchasePrice = Double.parseDouble(in.readLine());
            double cash = Double.parseDouble(in.readLine());
            Main.calculateChange(purchasePrice, cash);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    public static void calculateChange(double purchasePrice, double cash) {
        // Access your code here. Feel free to create other classes as required
        purchasePrice = purchasePrice*100;
        cash = cash*100;
        int PP = ((int)purchasePrice);
        int CH = ((int)cash);
        if (PP==cash){
            System.out.println("Zero");
        }
        else if(PP>CH){
            System.out.println("ERROR");
        }
        else if(PP<CH){
            int change = CH-PP;
            String changeList = "";

            modulusMe(change,changeList);
        }
    }

    public static void modulusMe(int change, String changeList){


        for (int i: cashMap.keySet()){
            System.out.println("Cents: " +i);
            if(i>change){
                System.out.println("Next");
                continue;
            }
            else{
                while(i<change){
                    System.out.println("Change before op: " +change);
                    change = change -i;
                    changeList = changeList+ cashMap.get(i);
                    System.out.println("Change after op: " +change);
                }
            }

        }
        System.out.println(changeList);
    }
}
```

Expected result of input 8.75 50 is Twenty Pounds, Twenty Pounds, One Pound, Twenty Pence, Five Pence
Expected result of input 11.25 20 is Five Pounds, Two Pounds, One Pound, Fifty Pence, Twenty Pence, Five Pence

Comment: Do watch the case of your words.  In your description you are searching "Five pence" but in the code you have "Five Pence".  These will not match in a hash search.

Answer (score 0):

`modulusMe` is skipping *Five Pence* because it's doing what it can to leave `change > 0`.

`while (i < change)` should be changed to `while (i <= change)`

```
while(i<change) { // should be while(i <= change)
    System.out.println("Change before op: " + change);
    change = change - i;
    changeList = changeList + cashMap.get(i);
    System.out.println("Change after op: " + change);
}
```